# Share image on Facebook

Tags: facebook, twitter, windows-phone-8

WP8 how to share data from my app to Facebook
or twitter
i want to take screen-shoot of my list-box and then share it on Facebook

i try this code 
 ShareLinkTask shareLinkTask = new ShareLinkTask();

```
        shareLinkTask.Title = "Code Samples";
        shareLinkTask.LinkUri = new Uri("https://www.facebook.com/", UriKind.Absolute);
        shareLinkTask.Message = "Here are some great code samples for Windows Phone.";

        shareLinkTask.Show();
```

but it doesnot work

Comment: What goes wrong? Errors? Please provide more info.

Comment: there is no error but also there is no result it is return to my page again

Comment: i try this code also ShareStatusTask sst = new ShareStatusTask();
            sst.Status = "hello test";
            sst.Show(); but the same result there is any action or data

Comment: ok it is should real device :(

Answer (score 0):

You should not use `ShareLinkTask` for sharing photos. You should use [`ShareMediaTask`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj207027%28v=vs.105%29.aspx). You can more information and how to implement `ShareMediaTask` by clicking link I provided herewith.

Here's the code:

```
CameraCaptureTask cameraCaptureTask = new CameraCaptureTask(); 
//declare it globally

cameraCaptureTask.Completed += cameraCaptureTask_Completed;
//declare it in Constructor

cameraCaptureTask.Show();
//declare it in any method.
```

For example, button click event. By using this method, you can capture the list box.

```
//declare this method anywhere in the cs page

   void cameraCaptureTask_Completed(object sender, PhotoResult e)
   {
        if(e.TaskResult == TaskResult.OK)
       {
           ShowShareMediaTask(e.OriginalFileName);
       }
   }
   void ShowShareMediaTask(string path)
   {
       ShareMediaTask shareMediaTask = new ShareMediaTask();
       shareMediaTask.FilePath = path;
       shareMediaTask.Show();
   }
```

Now, You can easily take screenshot of app's listbox and share it with any of the social networks where user installed on their phone. Cheers.!

Comment: check in the real device and be sure of checking screenshot when the method is called